# Как включить получение обновлений для Office через реестр?

Tags: windows, office, реестр, обновления

В настройках Центра обновления Windows имеется параметр: "При обновлении Winodws предоставить обновления для продуктов Майкрософт". По умолчанию он выключен (галка снята)! Существует ли твик реестра для установки данного параметра Центра обновления Windows? Интересуют варианты для Winodws 7, 8.1, 10.

Возможно данную задачу можно решить скриптом PS?

Comment: А рекомендации производителя помогли? [Office autoupdate](https://support.microsoft.com/ru-ru/help/2753538/automatic-updating-for-office-2013-and-office-2016-click-to-run-is-not)